# Replace an Azure DevOps Project wiki with an existing Code wiki

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a published code wiki in my azure devops project and I need to replace the existing Project wiki with the code wiki we already have. how can I do that?

Appreciate your help

I checked the repos and noticed that the Project wiki doesn't have a code repository which means this is not a simple cloning the code wiki repo and pushing to the project repo approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project wiki is also a git repo. You can clone and push changes to it. We can access it from `https://dev.azure.com/<Org_Name>/<Team_Project_Name>/_git/<Wiki_Name>`. See the detailed info from this official doc [How can I go to the Git repository?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-create-repo?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#how-can-i-go-to-the-git-repository)

The project wiki repo shown below can be accessed through the URL `https://dev.azure.com/<Org_Name>/<Team_Project_Name>/_git/Azure.wiki`.
[image]

Comment: you're absolutely right. It seems like project wiki is a hidden repo and you can only find it using the URL and not through the UI. Thanks for the help